# How to remove the fake k-points from vasprun.xml file in the calculation of HSE06 band structure?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, band-structure, hse06

Is there any script that can remove fake k-points from a `vasprun.xml` file for HSE06 band structure calculation? Because removing it manually is a time-consuming task.

Comment: How does one actually do this task?  Maybe something can be written.

Comment: You can first read the EIGENVAL file and then exclude all fake k-points.

Comment: What are fake k-points?

Comment: I am pretty sure "Fake" kpoints refer to the actual grid where the HSE06 band structure is calculated at 0 weight kpoints ontop of a normal kpoint grid

Comment: By fake k-points I mean zero weight k-points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here I write a python script to read the EIGENVAL of VASP to exclude the fake points used in the HSE06 band calculation, taking silicon as an example.

- https://github.com/Kohn-X/vasp_HSE06_band_read_and_plot

The final plot is the following:

[image]

Comment: That's a good script. Could you please add more comments to it, so it will be easier for the user to adopt it to any HSE06 bandstructure. Please indicate the lines that should be edited for every use.

Comment: This could have been an HNQ if you answered just 2 days earlier!

Comment: Can I change MATPLOTIB   in the plot script to another program?

Comment: This is a python script. Of course, you can change it if you are using another package supported by the Python language.

Comment: @샤다ㅏ May the Python environment is not OK.